# hyperledger: how to check authorization in the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have built a hyperledger chaincode for a blockchain service that contains all the regular init, invoke, read/write methods. However, to make it work in the real world, I need to add authorization check for which user can call which method. For example, user-A from peer-0 can call certain read/write while user-B from peer-1 can only call read.  I am not finding any examples so far, can someone please provide some example or guidelines on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To encode rules shared for all peers - You need to encode the ACL rules in the chaincode itself. Take a look at the [cid library](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.2/core/chaincode/lib/cid), it should make it easier.

To encode rules that are peer specific, you can implement custom [authentication filters](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L387-L399) - which intercept all chaincode proposals, and either pass them or reject them. Take a look at a native authentication filter that [prevents expired certificates from invoking chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go).